# Configure TestRestTemplate bean with proper root url in Spring Boot MVC Integration Test

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-test

I want to test my REST endpoints with a `TestRestTemplate` in a Spring Boot integration test but I don't want to write `"http://localhost" + serverPort + "/"` as prefix for each request all the time. Can  Spring configure a `TestRestTemplate`-bean with the proper root url and autowire it into my tests?

I don't want it to look like that:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class FoobarIntegrationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test()
    public void test1() {
        // out of the box I have to do it like this:
        testRestTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/my-endpoint", Object.class);

        // I want to do it like that
        //testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/my-endpoint", Object.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You need to provide a `@TestConfiguration` that registers a configured `TestRestTemplate`-bean. Then you can `@Autowire` this bean into your `@SpringBootTest`.

**TestRestTemplateTestConfiguration.java**

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestRestTemplateTestConfiguration {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate() {
        var restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().rootUri("http://localhost:" + port);
        return new TestRestTemplate(restTemplate);
    }

}
```

**FoobarIntegrationTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class FoobarIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test()
    public void test1() {
        // works
        testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/my-endpoint", Object.class);
    }
}
```